# Game Server Development for Beginner

Tags: sockets, server, network-programming, erlang, game-development

In these days I am working on turn based multiplayer game for mobile platforms. I am using my own game engine (OpenGL and Metal API for rendering). So I want to develop my own game server for multiplayer game experience. There are also some ready-made solutions for my problem but I want to gain this experience. I did some research because I was completely inexperienced, but some of the my questions are unanswered.

1. Which language is perfectly fit for game server development for beginners? I have some experience with RESTful API and some web technologies, this is my first time with realtime systems. Java, Go, Erlang and C++ looking good choices (I am good at Java).
2. Which libraries and techniques are useful for game server development. Is there any tool chain for rapid development process?
3. Is there any advised book or video tutorial about game server development?
4. I want to develop turn based game, is REST API good choice for this purpose?

I would love to hear your experiences

Answer (score 0):

1. Erlang. Uh, oh! For beginners?  Then elixir.  But IMO, really neither language is suitable for beginners.  I think erlang/elixir are intermediate/advanced languages.  On the other hand, python is a good beginner language, and python has pygame for game development, and there are beginner books in python for [making games](https://www.amazon.com/slp/python-game/pu5ahdurp4h83rp).
2. OTP, which is an erlang framework intimately entangled with erlang.  No RAD -- although emacs can whip up a skeleton gen_server for you.
3. You need to start any language with a beginning book.  The big two are `Programming Erlang` and `Erlang Programming` with `Programming Erlang` being the most recent.  After reading one of those books, your next step would be to dive deeper into OTP with `Designing for Scalability with Erlang/OTP: Implement Robust, Fault-Tolerant Systems`.
4. After you learn some erlang/OTP, you might not care much about REST, however there's [Building Scalable systems with Erlang and Rest](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/building-web-applications/9781449320621/ch01.html)